# Trying to run a docker command keeps giving me absolute path error

Tags: laravel, docker

Wanted to install laravel under windows 10 using git bash and it keeps giving me an error:

docker run --rm -v /d/programming/test/:/opt -w /opt laravelsail/php80-composer:latest bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"

Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/opt' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.

I've tried $(pwd), d:\...... /d/.... but it keeps giving that error.

No idea how to resolve this :-/

Comment: I recommend you to use `docker-compose` instead of plain `docker`, it will be way easier to configure/setup and then edit anything related to it, and it is mostly the way you are going to professionally use it.

Answer (score 3):

That's from Git Bash, it's converting paths to it's directory. To override that, use a double slash on the paths:

```
docker run --rm -v //d/programming/test/:/opt -w //opt laravelsail/php80-composer:latest bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"
```

Comment: This works perfectly (in gitbash)